# VS2013 C++ How to get same binary in Release mode as Debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am working with a Visual Studio 2013 C++ Application.  This application has always been used internally in Debug mode only. There is a good reason for this that I will not get into.  Now, we would like to distribute this application and therefore we must compile it in Release mode due to MS VS EULA.  The application runs some complex mathematical functions.  To avoid any additional testing I would like to get the same binary in Release as in Debug to ensure the output is the same in Debug and Release builds.

In Visual Studio I created a new Configuration that was based off of the Debug configuration.  I removed the #_DEGUG from the pre-processor defintion and I change the "Runtime Library" from **Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)** to **Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)**
All other options are copied from the Debug configuration. (ie there is no optimization etc)

The results are that the exe is slightly different and the results that are output when running the application are different.

Question:  Is there any way to get the same binary in Release mode as in Debug mode?  Or some other way to acheive this without violating the MS EULA.

Thank!
Pete

Comment: if you want to get the same binary with release as with debug, why dont you simply use the binary you get from debug? If the binaries should be the same as you want it, then anyhow one cannot tell the difference, or am I missing something?

Comment: My understanding of the MS EULA is that I can not distribute debug builds of applications and the associated MS libraries. In this case, the application uses MFC so I can not distribute the MFC libraries. We can required that the user provide these libraries but I dont think I can distribue the exe either.

Comment: @tobi303 -- you can't distribute the debug runtime that would be required by such binary. I suppose the user could try to use the static runtime.

Comment: @PXG Why does your release build produce different results than debug one? In what sense are they different?

Comment: My guess is UB or some floating point calculation flag is being set.

Comment: @DanMašek but then the debug and release binaries are necessarily different, no?

Comment: @Dan.  Hard to say at this point.  The output is a binary file.  When I compare using beyond compare, there are bytes here and there that are different.  99.99% of the file is the same.  I am not intimately familiar with the binary data at this time and I am hoping to avoid that If I can get identical outputs.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree.  But i can say with certainty that the options in the compiler are identical. At least the options that I can see.

Comment: Removing the _DEBUG define could certainly be enough.  The EULA does not state that you cannot distribute a debug build, it merely refers to redist.txt that says what Microsoft binaries you can distribute.  The debug build of the CRT is not included in that list.  So the only change that *actually* matters is /MDd to /MD.  If "output" is still different then you'll have to debug the code.  Well, not hard with the optimizer disabled :)

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks for the response.  I am looking again at the EULA and I agree.  I guess its other places that I have read this such as ->  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618(v=vs.100).aspx   I guess in the end it only matters what the EULA says.

Comment: Release binaries are optimized codes generated by the compiler and will always be superior and different from the debug counterpart.